# Allow google to access just one folder and block the rest of site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

EDIT: Doing this with robots.txt isn't good enough for me.

This code block entire site from google. I do not know how to keep this code functional but allow google to access one folder on the site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Does this works if i had 2 conditions?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} yahoo [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/allowed-folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Take a look at a robots.txt file instead

Comment: `Robots.txt` are good, `Robots.txt` obey us, `Robots.txt` has bling bling butt that never get hurt.

Comment: Doing this with robots.txt isn't good enough for me.

Comment: Doing with htaccess either, if someday you switch to another webserver you gonna get some headaches

Comment: This is why i want to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments create a file `robots.txt` under DOCUMENT_ROOT with following content:

```
User-Agent: googlebot
Disallow: /
Allow: /allowed-folder/
```

If you really want to handle this via mod_rewrite then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/allowed-folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Let him know about the headaches that `.htaccess` will bring if he switch webserver...

Comment: @IAmNotProcrastinating: Agreed that handling this task in `robots.txt` is much more cleaner.

Comment: htaccess is ok, just i would like to know what would be the code if i had 2 conditions - for example: 1) RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC] and 2) RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yahoo [NC]

Comment: @Zox I provided both option for your above however `robots.txt` is my personal preference for this task.

Comment: I will use both, however robots doesn't work well as i wouldn't want google to read my content at all.

Comment: How did you test it and what URL did you use to test?

Answer (score 1):

create file with name robots.txt

insert

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder you dont wont google inside in/
Disallow: /other folder you dont wont google inside in/
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it with htacess, i simply do not want google to be able to even read my content.